# using a shiny input as an argument of a function

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny dashboard that asks for text input and use that input as an argument for another package. Basically, this app should draw a research trend for any input that a user enters. The problem is that I got the following error, even if I use a `reactive` component for the text input.

`Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)`

Here is my code:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(europepmc)
library(cowplot)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    textInput("word","Please enter the word that you want to see its trend", "psychology"),
    sliderInput("from","From:",min = 1920, max = 2020, step = 1, value = 2000, sep = ''),
    sliderInput("to","To:", min = 1920, max = 2020, step = 1, value= 2020, sep = '')
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)
    )
  )
)






server <- function(input, output) {

  typed_word <- reactive({
    typed_word <- input$word

  })

  word_trend <- europepmc::epmc_hits_trend(query = typed_word(), #"psychology", 
                                           period = 2010:2020)
 
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    word_trend %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = factor(year), y = (query_hits / all_hits))) +
      geom_col(fill = "#56B4E9", width = 0.6, alpha = 0.9) +
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
      theme_minimal_hgrid(12) +
      labs(x = "Year", y = "Proportion of all published articles") +
      ggtitle(input$word)+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText(input$word)
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the `epmc_hits_trend` inside `renderPlot` function. Also you might want to make `from` and `to` as dynamic.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(europepmc)
library(cowplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    textInput("word","Please enter the word that you want to see its trend", "psychology"),
    sliderInput("from","From:",min = 1920, max = 2020, step = 1, value = 2000, sep = ''),
    sliderInput("to","To:", min = 1920, max = 2020, step = 1, value= 2020, sep = '')
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  typed_word <- reactive({
    typed_word <- input$word
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    word_trend <- europepmc::epmc_hits_trend(query = typed_word(), 
                                             period = input$from:input$to)
    word_trend %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = factor(year), y = (query_hits / all_hits))) +
      geom_col(fill = "#56B4E9", width = 0.6, alpha = 0.9) +
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
      theme_minimal_hgrid(12) +
      labs(x = "Year", y = "Proportion of all published articles") +
      ggtitle(input$word)+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText(input$word)
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ronak. Your solution solved the problem. I will add To and From to the reactive component as well. Thanks!